# JTable limited to 32 rows

Tags: java, swing, jtable

So, I've some data acquired by Arduino. I want to display (a simple integer) in a chart (I'm using jFreeChart) and a table (JTable).
The problems appears when I get more than 32 rows. The data isn't appended to JTable.
[Displayed Image] https://i.stack.imgur.com/nV8PJ.jpg
and
[Displayed graph] https://i.stack.imgur.com/Nj5EE.jpg

In this case, I've got 81 datas, but (always) only 32 are showed. (Yes, even if I scroll)

I really don't know what's happening. 
In this case `s1`,`s2` and `s3` are `TimeSeries` objects, `teste` is just a jLabel used to show how much data are available. `dtm` is a `DefaultTableModel`.

This code is in the main class (a JFrame)

```
public class MainForm extends javax.swing.JFrame {

    private DefaultTableModel dtm;
    //the rest of the code
```

In the Construcor (`tabela_dados` is the name of the JTable)

```
dtm = (DefaultTableModel) tabela_dados.getModel();
```

The method below  is called every time a new data is available in the `SerialPort` (using a `Listener` to do it)

```
public void update_TimeSeries(int t){

     LocalDateTime now = LocalDateTime.now();

     s1.addOrUpdate(new Millisecond(now.getNano()/1000000,now.getSecond(),now.getMinute(), 
now.getHour(), now.getDayOfMonth(), now.getMonthValue(), now.getYear()), 
            t);
     s2.addOrUpdate(new Millisecond(now.getNano()/1000000,now.getSecond(),now. now.getHour(), now.getDayOfMonth(), now.getMonthValue(), now.getYear()), 
             t*0.5);
     s3.addOrUpdate(new 
Millisecond(now.getNano()/1000000,now.getSecond(),now.getMinute(), 
now.getHour(), now.getDayOfMonth(), now.getMonthValue(), now.getYear()), 
            t*0.33);

      teste.setText(""+s1.getItemCount());

      //The place where I insert the data
      //Just to you guys understand, "t"  will be replaced by other variables further
      dtm.addRow(new Object[]{now.getSecond()+"."+now.getNano()/1000000,t,t,t});
}
```

It just should get as many data as a JTable can (I dont know how much is it, but it should be more than 32 rows hahaha)

Comment: At a guess, you didn't wrap the `JTable` into a `JScrollPane`, see [How to Use Tables](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html) and [How to Use Scroll Panes](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/scrollpane.html) for more details. If that doesn't answer your question, consider providing a [mcve] which clearly demonstrates your issue

Comment: Actually, the JTable is already into a JScrollPane. I guess that when I designed the JTable, a JScrollPane appeared there. Anyway, thanks for the tip[link](https://imgur.com/a/sYiMklv)

Comment: `the JTable is already into a JScrollPane` - then maybe you hardcoded a preferred size for the table so the scrolling doesn't work properly. Have you displayed the row count of the table? Without a proper "MCVE" we can't offer specific advice.

Comment: camick, HAHA, this is the problem. Indeed, I hardcoded the preferred size for the table (to guarantee that the table wouldn't get off the panel). But this wasn't really necessary. So I manually increased the preferred size and its working as it should haha. THANKS